# Oracle timestamp with local time zone values transparent translation

Tags: oracle, session, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

As far as I know, `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` values are transparently
translated to and from the user's session time zone. But my values read from
the database aren't the same as previously inserted. Is there a database or session
parameter I can tweak to fix this?

Here is my test case:

```
select systimestamp(0) from dual;

-- SYSTIMESTAMP   15/03/2017 19:01:13 +03:00

select dbtimezone from dual;

-- DBTIMEZONE     -07:00

create table test_timestamps
(
    id number generated by default on null as identity,
    systimestamp_col timestamp(0) with local time zone default on null systimestamp,
    sysdate_col timestamp(0) with local time zone default on null sysdate,
    current_timestamp_col timestamp(0) with local time zone default on null current_timestamp(0),
    date_col timestamp(0) with local time zone
);

alter session set time_zone='0:00';

insert into test_timestamps(date_col)
values (timestamp '2017-03-15 19:02:00');

select * from test_timestamps;

-- ID                                 1
-- SYSTIMESTAMP_COL                   15/03/2017 9:02:19
-- SYSDATE_COL                        15/03/2017 12:02:18
-- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_COL              15/03/2017 9:02:19
-- DATE_COL                           15/03/2017 12:02:00

delete from test_timestamps;

alter session set time_zone='+3:00';

insert into test_timestamps(date_col)
values (timestamp '2017-03-15 19:05:00');

select * from test_timestamps;

-- ID                                 2
-- SYSTIMESTAMP_COL                   15/03/2017 12:05:43
-- SYSDATE_COL                        15/03/2017 12:05:43
-- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_COL              15/03/2017 12:05:43
-- DATE_COL                           15/03/2017 12:05:00
```

I'm particularly confused about the `DATE_COL` value. As far as I know, the value I read from `DATE_COL` should be the same as I inserted no matter what the current session's `TIME_ZONE` is (as long as it's not changed between my insert and select).

I'm also puzzled with `SYSTIMESTAMP` default values.

`SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL` always returns my server's timestamp with '+3:00' time zone, regardless of the current user session's time zone. But if I use `SYSTIMESTAMP` as the default value for the column, it gets translated.

What I'd like to see is this:

```
-- for a user in my time zone
alter session set time_zone='+3:00';

insert into test_timestamps(date_col)
values (timestamp '2017-03-15 19:15:00');

select id, systimestamp_col, date_col from test_timestamps;

-- ID                                 3
-- SYSTIMESTAMP_COL                   15/03/2017 19:15:00
-- DATE_COL                           15/03/2017 19:15:00

-- same data from a GMT user's point of view
alter session set time_zone='+0:00';

select id, systimestamp_col, date_col from test_timestamps;

-- ID                                 3
-- SYSTIMESTAMP_COL                   15/03/2017 16:15:00
-- DATE_COL                           15/03/2017 16:15:00
```

Is that possible or am I missing something?

UPD. Here is my [LiveSQL script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:43:104748154482770:::43:P43_ID:99404190646095490242131686973772582940&cs=3NcEZSVHgfr84ubFLJMwIaMpel-5_S-aYUDkM0_MbE1OB20iEbj8P-E3S5PRNbomDoMO_ShyCsgteMnQMiCiKsw). It looks like it should work like I described, so I guess something might be wrong with my database setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our DBA have found the reason for this behavior.
We use a multitenant container database (Oracle 12c CDB).
The issue appears when the root database's `DBTIMEZONE` differs from the pluggable database's (PDB) `DBTIMEZONE`.

In our case, we had:

- root `DBTIMEZONE` — "0:00"
- PDB `DBTIMEZONE` — "-7:00"

Once the DBA had all `DBTIMEZONE`s set to the same value, the issue's gone.
As far as I understand, he'd changed the root `DBTIMEZONE` to "-7:00".
Now my test case runs exactly the same as on the [livesql.oracle.com](http://livesql.oracle.com) sandbox and the selected timestamp is the same as inserted.

Comment: btw, Oracle recommends that you set the database time zone to UTC, see [Setting the Database Time Zone](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#GUID-2AF15A96-CD19-4074-8DE6-17BAD0D7DF37__GUID-3F7611FB-D22B-4BD8-8352-41B01662300D)

Comment: I don't know why "-7:00" was set in the first place, but now, as the database has timestamp with local time zone fields, it's not easy to change that (pluggable databases have these fields, and the root database doesn't). So I guess the DBA just chose the minimal plausible change to fix the issue: he updated the dbtimezone of the root database.

Answer (score 6):

`TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` works like this: When you have to work with time zones in your application then a common approach is

> Store all times internally as UTC and convert them to current user local time zone on application level.

That's exactly how `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` works - the only difference is

> Store all times internally as **DBTIMEZONE** and convert them to current user local time zone on application level.

For that reason you cannot change `DBTIMEZONE` (with `ALTER DATABASE SET TIME_ZONE='...';`) on your database anymore if the database contains a table with a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column and the column contains data.

`SYSTIMESTAMP` is retured in time zone of database server's operating system. `DBTIMEZONE` is **not** the time zone of `SYSTIMESTAMP` or `SYSDATE`.

`DBTIMEZONE` defines the internal storage format of `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data type columns. Forget this, I cannot imagine any use-case where you would need it.

Actually your table is equivalent to this select:

```
select 
   CAST(systimestamp AS timestamp(0) with local time zone) as SYSTIMESTAMP_COL,
   CAST(sysdate AS timestamp(0) with local time zone) as SYSDATE_COL,
   CAST(current_timestamp AS timestamp(0) with local time zone) as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_COL,
   CAST(timestamp '2017-03-15 19:02:00' AS timestamp(0) with local time zone) as DATE_COL
from dual;
```

When you make `CAST({time without time zone} with local time zone)` then you try to convert a date/time value without any time zone information to a date/time value with time zone. In principle this is not possible because Oracle lacks the time zone information, so Oracle assumes a time zone. If you make such cast then Oracle always considers {time without time zone} as given in `SESSIONTIMEZONE` (in the moment of conversion).

So `CAST(sysdate AS timestamp(0) with local time zone)` is equivalent to

```
CAST(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE), SESSIONTIMEZONE) AS TIMESTAMP(0) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE)`
```

resp. `CAST(timestamp '2017-03-15 19:02:00' AS timestamp(0) with local time zone)` means

```
CAST(FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2017-03-15 19:02:00', SESSIONTIMEZONE) AS TIMESTAMP(0) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE)
```

For `SYSDATE` this is actually wrong, because `SYSDATE` is given in time zone of database server's operating system not in SESSIONTIMEZONE. For the second one it depends on your intention whether result is correct or not.

`SYSTIMESTAMP` returns value `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, it is always independent from your current `SESSIONTIMEZONE`. But if you convert to `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` it gets converted to your current local time zone, of course. You can also use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `SYSTIMESTAMP AT LOCAL` which does more or less the same.

This code

> ```
> select systimestamp(0) from dual;
>
> -- SYSTIMESTAMP   15/03/2017 19:01:13 +03:00
>
> alter session set time_zone='0:00';
>
> insert into test_timestamps(date_col)
> values (timestamp '2017-03-15 19:02:00');
>
> select * from test_timestamps;
>
> -- ID                                 1
> -- SYSTIMESTAMP_COL                   15/03/2017 9:02:19
> -- SYSDATE_COL                        15/03/2017 12:02:18
> -- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_COL              15/03/2017 9:02:19
> -- DATE_COL                           15/03/2017 12:02:00
> ```

seems to be wrong. Result should be

```
-- SYSTIMESTAMP_COL                   15/03/2017 16:01:14
-- SYSDATE_COL                        15/03/2017 19:01:14
-- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_COL              15/03/2017 16:01:14
-- DATE_COL                           15/03/2017 19:02:00
```

The differences look as it should be but the absolute values seems to be "faked" (or there is a real issue with your database).

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I included `DBTIMEZONE` because the values returned by my `SELECT` are off by 10 hours which looks like +7+3 (my server's time zone plus the dbtimezone value).

Comment: Nonetheless, I still can't figure how to do a simple roundtrip of a timestamp value on my database instance. If I insert a timestamp literal into my `DATE_COL` column (even cast as `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`), select returns the value offset by 10 hours. And it doesn't behave like this on other Oracle instances, for example on livesql.oracle.com, that's why I suspect some configuration issues.

Comment: When my session time zone is set to `0:00`, I insert `19:00` and get back `9:00`, that's off by 10 hours. When my session time zone is `+3:00` (same as database server's machine), I get `12:00`, that's off by 7 hours. Perhaps it's a coincidence that `DBTIMEZONE` is `-7:00`, but I suspect it may be related, that's why I though it worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried, your help is very appreciated! The values weren't faked, I posted everything as is. I was unable to reproduce the issue on a freshly created Oracle database and on [livesql.oracle.com](http://livesql.oracle.com), that's why I was so puzzled. Luckily, our DBA have just found the reason for this behavior, and I'm going to ask him for the details once he gets it fixed. It has something to do with the CDB settings, if I understand him right.